# Using getters to access Arraylist field of Arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm using a comparator to evaluate the equivalency of 2 objects that are in ArrayLists.  When I try to get the field values of the ArrayList (Services) of the ArrayList (Transactions) with getters from the targeted ArrayList  for the getters that I'm trying to use to access the fields in Service class. I have the getters for Service class created but im not sure how to properly access the field from twice removed ArrayLists.

This is in the customer class

```
ArrayList<Service> services = chckedTransaction.getServices(getServiceName, getPrice, getMechanics);
```

CUSTOMER CLASS

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private ArrayList<Transaction> transactioins;
    private ArrayList<Car> cars;


    public Customer(String name, String address, int phoneNumber, String carMake,
                    String carModel, int manufactureYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.transactioins = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        this.cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        createNewCar(carMake, carModel, manufactureYear);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public ArrayList<Transaction> getTransactioins() {
        return transactioins;
    }

    public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

private Transaction findTransaction(ServiceType serviceName, double price, Employee mechanic){
        ServiceComperator comperator = new ServiceComperator();
        Service dummyService = createDummyService(serviceName, price);
        for(int i=0; i<this.transactioins.size(); i++){
            Transaction chckedTransaction = this.transactioins.get(i);
            ArrayList<Service> services = chckedTransaction.getServices(getServiceName, getPrice, getMechanics);
            for(Service currentService : services){
                if(comperator.compare(dummyService, chckedTransaction.getServices())){

                }
            }
        }

private Service createDummyService(ServiceType serviceName, double price){
        Service dummyServices = new Service(serviceName, price);
        return dummyServices;
    }
```

TRANSACTIONS CLASS

```
public class Transaction {
    private ArrayList<Service> services;

    public Transaction() {
        this.services = new ArrayList<Service>();
    }


    public ArrayList<Service> getServices() {
        return services;
    }
```

SERVICE CLASS

```
public class Service {
    private ServiceType serviceName;
    private double price; //might need to use a link list double
    private ArrayList<Employee> machanics;


    public Service(ServiceType serviceName, double price) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.price = price;
        this.machanics = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }


    public ServiceType getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public ArrayList<Employee> getMachanics() {
        return machanics;
    }

    public void addEmployee(String mechanicName){
        machanics.add(new Employee(mechanicName));
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Service> services = chckedTransaction.getServices(getServiceName, getPrice, getMechanics);` The `getServices` method does not take any arguments.  Just use `getServices()`  It will return the `ArrayList` containing `Service` objects.

Comment: ok, thanks that makes sense but how would I go about getting the field values for the service array from the customer class The Transactions Array has a ArrayList field of Services. I need to get the field values in the Servies array object.

Comment: The `ArrayList` uses indices just like arrays.  So once you get the list, you can do `list.get(0), list.get(1).. etc`  The `list.size()` is the size of the list.  Check out the ArrayList documentation to see other methods that may be of use.

Comment: @WJS is correct, `getServices()` does not take any arguements, however you are passing 3 parameters `chckedTransaction.getServices(getServiceName, getPrice, getMechanics);`. I couldn't understand your comment but I believe, to get the services from the `transaction` field in customer class, you would need to do something like this:  
`chckedTransaction.getServices().getServiceName()` and so on for other Services class fields.

Comment: When I do ArrayList<Service> services = chckedTransaction.getServices().getSericeName() I get cannot resolve getServiceName in array List

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had some missing parameters for the create and find methods.
Thanks, guys for pointing out the missing parameters. I made the changes and now it compiles just fine.

Customer class

```
public boolean createNewTransaction(ServiceType serviceName, double price,
                                    Employee mechanic, String mechanicName){
    Transaction existingTransaction = findTransaction(serviceName, price, mechanic);
    if(existingTransaction == null){
        Transaction newTransaction = new Transaction();
        newTransaction.createNewService(serviceName, price, mechanic, mechanicName);
        this.transactioins.add(newTransaction);
    }
    return false;
}

    private Transaction findTransaction(ServiceType serviceName, double price, Employee mechanic){
            ServiceComperator comperator = new ServiceComperator();
            Service dummyService = createDummyService(serviceName, price);
            for(int i=0; i<this.transactioins.size(); i++){
                Transaction chckedTransaction = this.transactioins.get(i);
                ArrayList<Service> services = chckedTransaction.getServices();//.getSericeName();
                for(Service currentService : services){
                    if(comperator.compare(dummyService, currentService) == 0){
                        return this.transactioins.get(i); // not sure if this is correct or not
    
                    }
    
                }
    
            }return null;
        }
```